# Convert decimal to char/string

Tags: c, string, char, decimal

Let's say i have this number

```
int x = 65535;
```

Which is the decimal representation of:

> ÿÿ

I know how i can do it from single char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int f = 65535;
    printf("%c", f);
}
```

But this will only give me "ÿ"

I would like to do this without using any external library, and preferably using C type strings.

Comment: `Let's say i have this number

int x = 65535;
Which is the decimal representation of:

ÿÿ`
wat?

Comment: i might have explained it wrongly, ÿÿ is for 65535, as "49" is for "1". As ÿ is 255 in decimal, ÿÿ is (255*256)+255 = 65535

Comment: ÿ is 255 in Latin-1 or Windows-1252.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned f = 65535; // initial value

    // this will do the printf and ff >>= 8 until f <= 0 ( =0 actually)
    do {
      printf("%c", f & 0xff); // print once char. The &0xff keeps only the bits for one byte (8 bits)
      f >>= 8; // shifts f right side for 8 bits
    } while (f > 0);
}
```

Consider the value 65535, or 0xffff in hexadecimal, meaning its positive value takes 2 bytes that are 0xff and 0xff

- print of `f & 0xff` keeps only the 8 LSb, (0xffff & 0xff = 0xff)
- `f >> = 8` shifts the value 8 bits to the right, 0xffff becomes 0x00ff (the 'ff' right side are gone
- `f > 0` is true since `f == 0xff` now

Next loop is the same, but `f >>= 8` shifts 0x00ff to the right => 0x0000, and f is null.
Thus the `f > 0` condition is wrong and the loop ends.

Comment: That will work with his specific values, but not generally.  (What happens, for example, if `x > 65535`?)

Comment: Well.. i need for bigger values too, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is bit masking: `(x >> 8) & 0xFF` for
the high order byte, and `(x & 0xFF)` for the lower.  (Actually,
if `int` has 32 bits, it's `(x >> 24) & 0xFF` for the high order
byte.  But given the values, and what you say your expecting,
you probably want the second byte, and not the high order byte.)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a 16 bit (two bytes) unsigned number. A `char` is 8 bits (one byte). This means you have to extract the two bytes in the number to get them as separate character.

This is done with the bitwise operators. You can use bitwise and `&` and bitwise shift `>>` to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
char buffer[9];
long value = 65535;
char *cur = buffer;
while (value > 0)
{
    *cur++ = value % 0x100;
    value /= 0x100;
}
*cur = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry.. but what is this? Could you explain?